# Cannot POST using node & Express (Jade, MongoDB, Express, Node)

Tags: node.js, post, express, pug

I have a form in which a user can select a .xlsx file and upload it:

```
      p Upload New Schedule
      #uploadNew
        form(id = "form1", action="/uploadNew", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
          input(type="file", id="control", name="XLupload")
          br
          input(type="submit" value="Upload" name="Submit")
```

in my main app.js I have this route to deal with it.

```
var uploads = require('./routes/upload');
//Make the db accessible to various http requests
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.db = dbMain;
  next();
});
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/upload', uploads);
```

and In my upload.js file I have the following:

```
var xlsx = require('xlsx');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: './uploads'});
var excel_upload = upload.single('XLupload');

router.get('/upload', stormpath.groupsRequired(['Enforced']), function(req, res) {
    res.render('upload', {
        title: 'Uploading Excel File'
    });
    next();
});

router.post('/upload', excel_upload, function(req, res) {
    // Get the path to the uploaded Excel file
    var fileObject = req.file;
    var filePath = fileObject.path;

    // Get collection instance which will store the data from the newly posted schedule
    var dbLocal = req.db;
    var insertionCollection = dbLocal.collection('chip');
    .....
```

However, when I start up and listen at localhost, when I select a file and try to upload I get error cannot POST /upload.  When I did not have routes and had everything in the main app.js file, this was not an issue.  What did I mess up by introducing routes?

Comment: I dont see `router` being defined in `upload.js`

Comment: In upload.js,  add var router = express.Router();

Comment: Aside from 'router' not being defined in your example, posting the error you said you received would also be beneficial to others helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
app.use('/upload', uploads);
```

Combined with this:

```
router.post('/upload', ...)
```

Declares this route: `POST /upload/upload`

If you *mount* a router (using `app.use(PATH, router)`), `PATH` adds a prefix to all the routes handled by that router. Your router need to declare routes relative to that prefix:

```
router.post('/', ...)
```